# What is the frequency of drop items at the end of each game?

Tags: dota-2

Every week I see how other players obtain items at the ends of the games. For example, parts of armor sets. I have played many hours of Counter Strike Go and in that game the loot refreshes every week. But I don't know if this system is the same in Dota 2.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In *Dota 2* there is an Item drop system:

The *item drop system* is a feature that allows players to obtain cosmetic items for free through playing the game.

> Notes:
>
> - After every matchmaking game, each player has **a small chance** to receive an item or set.
> - All drops in Dota 2 are solely based on time played in Dota 2 via matchmaking.
> - Winning, losing, or individual performance has no effect on item drop chance.

And also:

While *spectating* a tournament game with over 100 viewers, one or more **Heroic items** are randomly given out to viewers each time a memorable event occurs.

For more information about *Item drop system* read [this](https://dota2.gamepedia.com/Item_drop_system).

Comment: While providing a lot of information, this doesn't address the question.

Comment: So, I shouldn't understand the question! Can you tell me what is the question? - I thought it is *What is the frequency of drop items at the end of each game?* ;).

Answer (score 1):

From my personal experience, I can say that there is no loot refresh system in Dota 2. The stuff is awarded randomly. Last week I've got like 2 pieces of different item sets and of different quality, but haven't got any items at all for like half a year or so.

Answer (score 0):

The exact chance of getting an item at the end of the game was not disclosed by Valve but they stated:

> All drops in Dota 2 are solely based on time played in Dota 2 via matchmaking.

So I guess the longer the match, the higher the chances of getting an item (something I did notice after very long games, having an increase on the number of players that usually receives items)

One thing I have noticed is that the chance is purely random and not RNG as most of the in-game chances (it does not increase if there are multiple games without receiving)